# Condensing 5 lists containing 30 dictionaries each into single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I have 5 lists that contain 30 dictionaries each. Each dictionary has two key value pairs, team_name and fd_points which represents how many points per game that team gives up to that opposing position, for example:

```
point_guards = [
{'team_name': 'NOR', 'fd_points': '56.15'},
{'team_name': 'ORL', 'fd_points': '53.72'},
] 

shooting_guards = [
{'team_name': 'NOR', 'fd_points': '57.13'},
{'team_name': 'ORL', 'fd_points': '43.72'},
]
```

I would like to condense all these lists into a dataframe that I will write to a csv in which the final product shows each team name as rows across 5 columns each column representing the amount of points that team gives up to each opposing position.

```
NOR, PG_points, SG_points, SF_points, PF_points, C_points
ORL, PG_points, SG_points, SF_points, PF_points, C_points
```

If there is a better way to go about it than putting all of the data into a dataframe I'm open to suggestions, I have other data I scrape and put into a dataframe then write to a csv, so that's why I chose that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from your 2 lists of dictionaries I created another list - the
source for *SF_points*:

```
sf_src = [
    {'team_name': 'NOR', 'fd_points': '44.01'},
    {'team_name': 'ORL', 'fd_points': '49.12'}]
```

The first step is to create individual DataFrames, holding these 3 lists:

```
pg = pd.DataFrame(point_gaurds).rename(columns={'fd_points': 'PG_points'}).set_index('team_name')
sg = pd.DataFrame(shooting_gaurds).rename(columns={'fd_points': 'SG_points'}).set_index('team_name')
sf = pd.DataFrame(sf_src).rename(columns={'fd_points': 'SF_points'}).set_index('team_name')
```

Print each of them separately.

Note that:

- *fd_points* column is in each case has been renamed to the name to
  be present in the result,
- in each case *team_name* is set as the index.

Then, to create one "composite" DataFrame, run:

```
result = pg.join(sg).join(sf)
```

And to create the output CSV file, run:

```
result.to_csv()
```

The result is:

```
team_name,PG_points,SG_points,SF_points
NOR,56.15,57.13,44.01
ORL,53.72,43.72,49.12
```

In my opinion the first row (column names) is needed to show the meaning of
each column. If you want to omit this line, run instead:

```
result.to_csv(header=False)
```

To have a "full" result, with 2 remaining columns:

- define respective "src" lists,
- create respective DataFrames from them, suitably renaming *fd_points*,
  column,
- add `.join(...)` to the instruction generating the *result* DataFrame.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you for the detailed answer and all the help - cheers mate